# resetPassword function isn't working in Mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, ionic-framework

I am using sendResetPasswordEmail in the Ionic React app to reset the user password, we have got the new password in the database and we try to use resetPassword in Realm > Build > Functions resetPassword function, I know I need to use: `await app.emailPasswordAuth.resetPassword(token, tokenId, password)`, however, I just can't get the app working: `let app = new Realm.App(appConfig); const Realm = require("realm");` It's either undefine app or realm modules.

[here is part of the code in the functions and the errors that show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PofOY.png)

Comment: It will be helpful if you showed the actual code and any errors

Comment: @AaronSaunders Hi Aaron, I just updated the image of the function i am using the the error it shows in mongodb, thank you